# Unstructured data of excel sheet to structured data

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

I have a bunch of 100 excel sheets. These sheets have entries like name, father name, address, email-id, phone_no., tower_no, etc..

The problem is that, I want those details which have multiple property in one excel sheet or more excel sheet. These sheet have entries of customer who bought the property.

But the situation is that data entry operator entered the data in random manner like : as he entered name, added email-id in same column so it is difficult to make data base(MY SQL) for this, so that I can get my feasible results.

Comment: To have an automated process you need to have some degree of standard. I do not think that having multiple files with different structures is a standard, thus I doubt that what you are after is possible without some human going through the files and making sure that they adhere to the same format.

Comment: amazon mechanical turk is your friend